# Historical mid-reuters currency exchange rates

Tags: currency, quotes

I would like to cross-check exchange rate used for a transaction. Exchange rate used for the transaction is based on mid-reuters (the average between reuters bid and ask rates) plus a margin.

Is there any site to obtain historical mid-reuters exchange rate for a pair of currencies at a specific date and time? The shorter the period, the better. Preferably 1 minute low/high quotes, but longer periods of up to 1 hour may also work. Chart is not needed, but is an acceptable alternative.

Comment: Maybe define "mid-reuters" for those who don't know the term? I suspect that anything approaching the granularity you are asking for us (a) expensive and (2) not as useful as you might hope

Comment: Can you suggest the right definition please or edit the question yourself? Is it possible for 5, 10, 30 minutes or even 1 hour then? It is helpful for me and may be helpful for others to cross-check exchange rate of a transaction.

Comment: I can't suggest a definition; I have no idea what was meant. Which is why I suggested that more answers might appear if it was clarified. Also, editing to explain that your goal is to confirm exchange rates for past transactions, rather than to try to predict the future (if I'm understanding correctly) might help folks suggest approaches/alternatives.

Comment: What Reuters bid and ask rate. Potentially a Reuters fixing at a certain time? It's rather unusual to simply specify the use of a mid rate without additional details. See [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/156234/109107) for some details. What pair, date and time would also help. If you know the margin you know the rate. Just compare with a fixing and unless you are great off it should be fine (it almost always is as it's all automated usually).

Comment: "It's rather unusual to simply specify the use of a mid rate" => Get Yahoo or Google. They don't show bid and ask prices. They expose only one price. What is this price? Mid rate, isn't it?